# AVAssetTrack recorded dimensions

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

I know how to get `natural` (displayed) dimensions of video from `AVAssetTrack` (using `[track naturalSize]`, but how do I get the `native` dimensions? For example when I open a video in QuickTime, I see format: `H.264 800 x 566 (1006 x 566)`

`naturalSize` returns 1006, and I need to get this 800. How do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read that in the video track's format description:

```
CMVideoFormatDescription *desc = [[track formatDescriptions] first];

CMVideoDimensions dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(desc);

NSLog(@"%i x %i", dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
```